# window.open addEventListener does not work on "Mobile Browser Simulator"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mbs

I'm using IBM Worklight 6.2

I'm using window.open to load some external pages for OAuth and I configure event listeners for the opened window.

```
var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank', 'location=yes');

authWindow.addEventListener('loaderror', function(e) {  
    console.log(">> load error. event: " + JSON.stringify(e));
});
```

also for "load" and "loadstart" events.

This works in Android and iOS but when I preview the app in the "Mobile Browser Simulator" the eventListeners are not executed.

I have also tested creating a "desktopbrowser" application.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loaderror, loadstart, and loadstop are specific to Cordova and not supported in the Mobile Browser Simulator. It would be best to test these on emulator or device. Please see: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#addEventListener

Comment: In Mobile Browser Simulator you also have access to the Cordova features, for example access to the GPS or Camera. Is there any kind of rule to know which features of Cordova are available in the Simulator?

Comment: Please see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/tpreview_Cordovawl.html?lang=en